# Checking memory on several RPi's with one command

Tags: command-line, memory, raspberry-pi

So I have 3 active Raspberry Pi's. I want to check their memory by using one command only in the console of one of the RPi's.
First thing that came to mind was using sshpass like so:

`free -h & sshpass -p 'password' ssh pi@ip2 free -h & sshpass -p 'password' ssh pi@ip3 free -h`

This command does show memory of the 1st and 2nd RPi. However no information from 3rd RPi is shown.

Any suggestions on how I could get the wanted memory information for all the 3 active RPi's?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using password authentication and not public key authentication? ... Typically I use `&&` in multi-command chains...  If you are looking to find out what the third `ssh` is doing try the `-vv` option...

Answer (score 1):

Well, first I would suggest using public key authentication with SSH as suggested by RubberStamp in the comments, that will cut down on the size of the command-line significantly.

Now, if you want something simpler than that, you're going to need to do some further setup work, but any such solution will usually let you do a lot more than just check free memory.

There are two approaches you can take:

1. Create a system monitoring setup that you can query.  This has the advantage that you can also usually see historical data, and depending on the tool may not even have to log in to get the info you want.
2. Configure an orchestration tool to let you easily query all three systems directly at the same time.  This won't let you track historical data (though it can make it easier to set up and maintain system monitoring that can do that), but it can also be used for a wide variety of other things, like automating software management on the three systems.

Popular options for the first approach include:

- [Collectd](http://collectd.org/):  This is what most pre-built systems (things like firewalls and NAS systems) use.  It can be somewhat resource hungry and takes some significant effort to set up, but it provides great options for data collection, and insane flexibility in data retrieval.  If you go this way, I suggest setting up a dedicated system to store the data.
- [Netdata](https://my-netdata.io/): This is what I use on all my systems.  It handles most of the configuration work itself and uses a miniscule amount of resources compared to collectd, but needs some extra work to store data persistently, and only tracks data from the last hour by default (and  increases the resource usage).

Popular options for the second approach include:

- [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/): Dead simple to use, install it on one system, and you're good to go (the only dependency for systems managed through Ansible is already installed on almost all modern Linux distributions).  Configuration is simple (you quite literally just need to tell it what systems you want to manage and make sure you have working authentication via SSH), and it has provisions to just issue one-off commands to everything.
- [Puppet](https://puppet.com/): Not quite as easy to set up as Ansible (it requires software running on all the managed systems as well as the system doing the managing), but still very popular.  I've never used it myself, so I can't comment much beyond that.
- [Chef](https://www.chef.io/): Similar to Puppet, also very popular, and also something I can't comment more on because I haven't used it myself.
- [PolySH](http://guichaz.free.fr/polysh/): A simple SSH wrapper designed to do pretty much exactly what you're trying to do (except it's designed specifically for interactive usage).  Requires no special support on the target systems beyond working SSH authentication.  Similar options can be found by consulting basic cluster management HOWTO's (as most such tools were designed for Beowulf clustering).